# Android - chromium webview crashing after celect text

Tags: android, webview, chromium

i use chromium webview function in app. After select text for copy app crashed...

When you try to select text to copy, the copy option does not appear. The application crashes immediately. I have no idea how to solve this problem, so I will be very happy for any help ... thank you ...

```
    D/SmartSelectEventTracker:  1: SMART_SELECTION_SINGLE/other, range=0,1 - smart_range=0,1 (webview/)
W/studio.gamegai: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
E/studio.gamegai: No package ID 02 found for ID 0x020b001b.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nijastudio.gamegain, PID: 11819
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20b001b
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1094)
        at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.a(PG:9)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl.a(PG:211)
        at aen.onCreateActionMode(PG:15)
        at bCD.onCreateActionMode(PG:6)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onCreateActionMode(DecorView.java:2383)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:887)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:843)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:985)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:985)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:985)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:985)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:985)
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:6796)
        at bzf.a(PG:1)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl.g(PG:127)
        at bDD.a(PG:31)
        at bDa.a(PG:14)
        at aix.handleMessage(PG:11)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Pleas help me...

Comment: Search for resource ID `0x020b001b` in the generated R.java file to know what it is.

Comment: @Pavel Kudris Kudrna Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some researching I found that downgrading androidx app compat version from 1.1.0 to 1.0.2 solved the problem.

Hope this helps!
If you have already found an other solution, please let me know! :)